# create animation in iOS project like Adobe after effect

Tags: ios, core-animation, uianimation

I have to create the same animation like http://dribbble.com/shots/1078726-Animated-UI-AE-giveaway in my iOS application.

Is there any iOS SDK for the same which can be used for this?

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

That depends on what SDK support you are looking for. You can rotate views in 3D space with a perspective using Core Animation allowing you to fold them.

I would recommend that you read this article about [the Anatomy of a Folding Animation](http://markpospesel.wordpress.com/2012/05/10/anatomy-of-a-folding-animation/). That should get started with folding views. The rest seems to be applying the same kind of fold animation many different times on different parts of the UI.

Answer (score 0):

You will not get any ready made project same as you want.

But you can always learn from example.

If you really want to learn animation in iOS that you should read:

[Basic iOS 6 iPhone Animation using Core Animation](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Basic_iOS_6_iPhone_Animation_using_Core_Animation)

You can alo refer Apple iOS document of Core Animation: [About Core Animation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/Introduction/Introduction.html)

If you want to see example from some developer that visit : [Search results for animation](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=animation)

This two I think very related to you :

- [FlipTransform for iOS](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/fliptransform)
- [MPFoldTransition for iOS](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/mpfoldtransition)
- [PaperFold-for-iOS](https://github.com/honcheng/PaperFold-for-iOS)

Comment: I am not asking for any ready made project, just an idea or refrence to any SDK which supports it and thanks for the links you provided